# Retrieving Dictionary from Firebase is 'nil'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have the following database structure...
[image]

Here is my what I'm using to populate my Post model:

```
func observePost(withId id: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> Void) {
    REF_POSTS.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let post = Post.transformPostPhoto(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
            completion(post)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above snippet, REF_POSTS is pointing to the posts node on the Firebase db.

I am able to retrieve the 'question' text fine, but 'answers' is coming back as nil. I have done research in regards to retrieving a dictionary within a dictionary (I think this is whats happening).

I'm having a hard time phrasing this question so it will have some edits, any information would be great.

Comment: Post your complete snapshot to get an answer.

Comment: Added..sorry I am still figuring out Firebase. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Could you please print post for me to see the data structure coming from the Firebase, and make sure the answers are in the post? `print(post)`

Comment: Try this: `if let answers = snapshot.value["answers"] as? <String, Any> {
    print(answers)
}`

Comment: Or this might also works: `let answers = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").value`

Comment: Did this help? `let answers = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").value`

Comment: Yes absolutely. I added that into the observePost method after the first if/let statement and I was able to successfully print out the answers. Now I need to get that information into my Model. You have been very helpful so far. Thanks :)

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Comment: This is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) that has already been solved: [accessing nested firebase data in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993362/accessing-nested-firebase-data-in-swift), [Work with Lists of Data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data), [Firebase and reading nested data using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797626/firebase-and-reading-nested-data-using-swift)

Comment: @RLoniello you're totally right. Just couldn't get it working and turned to SO. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to look for answers:

```
let answers = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "answers").value
```